# New install, always boots to grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a machine. When I try to boot I get sent to grub, and entering the following commands allows me to boot correctly:

```
set root=(hd0,4)   
linux (hd0,4)/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic root=/dev/sda4  
initrd (hd0,4)/boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic  
boot
```

I have gone into the system, run an update, run `sudo update-grub` (no errors), shut down and booted back up. I still get sent into grub rather than straight to ubuntu. What is going wrong?

Comment: `sudo update-grub` just updates menu. Is this an UEFI install or a BIOS install. You need to install grub to MBR if BIOS or into ESP - efi system partition if  UEFI install. Best to know details, so we can make better suggestions. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info In almost all cases Boot-Repair works, but in some very special cases it may not, so best to see details first.

Comment: Following the instructions in the first part, my pastebin link is http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3sr7v2Xw5Z/

Comment: It looks like you have installed in both UEFI and BIOS boot mode as you have the ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot and a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. And grub installed in MBR (BIOS) and in ESP. It looks like you are currently configured for BIOS boot as line 103 of report shows UEFI boot looking for UUID/partition that does not exist. You should be able to boot from UEFI, but with BIOS/Legacy/CSM on & UEFI off. You can easily convert to UEFI boot with Boot-Repair/Intaller booted in UEFI mode and in advanced options the full uninstall/reinstall of grub.

Comment: Thanks, running boot repair from terminal seems to have sorted it out.